# Which method gives better performance?

Tags: java, performance, jasper-reports

Which one should I use for a better performance generating reports in Jasper?

```
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, datasource);
```

or,

```
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code: [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/4.0.1/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.java#JasperFillManager.fillReport%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport%2Cjava.util.Map%2Cjava.sql.Connection%29).  Select the version that matches what you are using.

In the version I looked at, it makes almost no difference.  If you provide a connection, the filler code will internally create a datasource from the connection.  From then on, the performance should be the same as if you had turned the connection into a datasource yourself.

(And this is what you would expect they would do for the various convenience overloads.)